# Do semantics matter in Latex? If not, why not?

Tags: latex

When I ask questions about achieving some particular layout LaTeX, I get answers that suggest I should use constructs that don't make sense for their semantics. For example, I wanted to intent a single paragraph, and I was told to make it a list with no bullets. It works, but that isn't the semantic meaning of a list, so why is it acceptable to abuse it like that.

We stopped doing it in HTML over a decade ago. Why are we still doing the equivalent of table layout in supposedly the best typesetting system there is?

Am I not getting it, but isn't this a little inelegant? Everyone says LaTeX is elegant and that you don't need to worry about layout, but then I find myself contorting tables, lists and other semantic markup to put stuff where I want it. Does the emperor have no clothes, or am I not getting it?

Comment: I'd ask this on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I totally agree. In theory LaTeX is elegant, but in practice it is hard to work with and finding good documentation is a pain in the behind.

Comment: It will produce nice looking documents though. But it's a steep learning curve, and I do think that it feels kinda last century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a problem like this comes along, and the answer is to use something that doesn't really make semantic sense, what you should do is create a new environment or command that wraps the functionality in a way that makes semantic sense.

Every layout language has this problem -- somewhere along the line, you need to get down to a physical, non-semantic solution. In HTML, the non-semantic parts of the solution are now pretty-well covered by by CSS and JavaScript (which are different languages from HTML). You create `<div>`s and `<span>`s that capture the semantics, and then you use CSS and JavaScript to define the physical layout for those semantics.

In LaTeX, you simply wind up using the exact same language for this purpose: LaTeX (or plain TeX, which is often hard to differentiate from LaTeX).

Comment: Separation of concerns is an important deal in HTML, CSS, and Javascript. This orthogonality helps with modularization, and is honoured in other areas of software engineering as well.

The fact that HTML captures semantics while CSS doesn't allows machines to read and understand HTML.

However, having a single language for both presentation and content is unsuitable for this. How does LaTeX solve this problem? How do we ascribe meaning to semantics like we do in HTML? And how can we separate semantics from presentation if the same language is used for both?

Comment: @dionyziz Writing a LaTeX document isn't software engineering. Software engineering principles don't automatically apply. That said, (La)TeX *does* provide you with ways of separating content and presentation: you can wrap the "semantically incorrect" constructs in a `\newcommand`, and pretend that what you use to implement the `\newcommand` are just badly named purely layout-focused constructs with zero semantic meaning.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it's all a matter of knowing or finding the right semantics. You talk about a single example, and you don't provide your semantics, you talk about the way to layout it. So depending on what it is that you want indented, there might be better fits, e.g. a quote, a formula, etc.